# how can I format a generated HTML source code?

Tags: php, html

this code

```
$table_rows = '';
foreach ($result as $row) {           
  $tr = '<tr>';
  $tr = $tr . '<td>' . $row['crn_name'] . '</td>';
  $tr = $tr . '<td>' . $row['crn_code'] . '</td>';
  $tr = $tr . '</tr>';            
  $table_rows = $table_rows . $tr;
}
```

generates this output

```
<tr><td>forint</td><td>Ft</td></tr><tr><td>euro</td><td>€</td></tr>
```

It works, but the source code of the page looks terrible. I would like to produce a code which is much more easy to read. Somthing like that:

```
<tr>
  <td>forint</td>
  <td>Ft</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>euro</td>
  <td>€</td>
</tr>
```

what should I do?!

Comment: Have a look at [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

Comment: Why do you want it to be pretty? Your browser's developer tools' tree view displays the DOM exactly the same with and without whitespace.

Comment: Also consider why you want it to be readable. In production, unless you have to support a use case that requires viewing of source code, whitespace does nothing but increase page weight. If you're requiring it for debug, then Firebug or a webkit inspector will automatically format your elements in the appropriate view.

Comment: Why on earth would you even care how badly formatted the rendered html is??

Comment: ^^ + the original is is also smaller, therefore faster/ less bandwidth

Comment: `echo str_repeat(" ", 10).'<td>';` but this will have a negative effect on performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tidy is probably too much. Just use the alternate syntax:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?= $row['crn_name']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?= $row['crn_code']; ?> </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add suitable whitespace to your output. This is easier if you output your HTML directly and only dip into PHP mode when you need PHP.

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['crn_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['crn_code']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this without meticulously inserting line breaks, tabs and spaces where they really stick out like a sore thumb would be to use [tidy](http://www.php.net/tidy).

```
    $config = array(
            'indent'         => true,
            'output-xhtml'   => true,
            'show-body-only' => true,
            'wrap'           => false);

    $tidy = new tidy;
    $tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use return **\r** or newline **\n**

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.
Just put teal tab there you want spaces and \n back each line.

Something like that

```
    $table_rows = '';
    foreach ($result as $row) {           
      $tr = '\n';
      $tr = $tr . '     ' . $row['crn_name'] . '\n';
      $tr = $tr . '     ' . $row['crn_code'] . '\n';
      $tr = $tr . '\n';            
      $table_rows = $table_rows . $tr;
    }
```

or you can use only space. But \n <-- for new line. Good luck!

`$table_rows = '';
foreach ($result as $row) {           
  $tr = '<tr>\n';
  $tr = $tr . '  <td>' . $row['crn_name'] . '</td>\n';
  $tr = $tr . '  <td>' . $row['crn_code'] . '</td>\n';
  $tr = $tr . '</tr>\n';            
  $table_rows = $table_rows . $tr;
}`